# CellFind function in VBA

Tags: vba, find, cell

its formula I can do this. but vba I dont know code simple word
A1 = "Melodies Red Dragraon"

I want find text "Red". If found "Red" = Yes its red. how to write or interest this

```
    Range("A3").Select
Cells.Find(What:="red", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

The Question its OK Question Range A1 = Melodies Red Dragraon I want search text From Range A1 "Red" if found red in range A1 A2 = you found great

I want puy to my export pdf Old code

```
Dim codebranch As String
Dim branchname As String 
Dim lictype As String 
On Error GoTo errHandler

lictype = Mid(Range("B5"), 48, 7)
```

you found great_All _003_Lumpini_03_04_60.pdf

Full code PDF Here

```
Sub Button28_PDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim codebranch As String
Dim branchname As String
Dim lictype As String
On Error GoTo errHandler


lictype = Mid(Range("B5"), 48, 7)
codebranch = Left(Range("A1"), 3)
branchname = Mid(Range("A1"), 7, 50)
Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "dd_mm_yy")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = lictype & "_" & codebranch & "_" & branchname & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: please give some more details (examples?) about your goal

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
Dim Rng As Range
'Range("A3").Select
Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:="red", After:=Range("A3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    'do whatever you want to do with Rng cell found
End If
```